# viewdidappear is not called from tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `TabBarController` with `NavigationController`... the main `TabController` has some buttons which i want to add borders to... am doing this in `ViewDidAppear` but its not called! when i go to child controller and click back button its called now .. but when firstly click the tab is not called!

and what am doing is this in the main tab vc:

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if MOLHLanguage.isArabic(){
        aboutusbtn.addRightBorderHome( borderWidth: 3)
        rulesbtn.addRightBorderAboutus(borderWidth: 3)
        committeebtn.addRightBorderHistory(borderWidth: 3)
        generalbtn.addRightBorderShare(borderWidth: 3)
        publickbtn.addRightBorderHome(borderWidth: 3)
        contactusbtn.addRightBorderAboutus(borderWidth: 3)
    }else{
        aboutusbtn.addLeftBorderHome(width: 3)
        committeebtn.addLeftBorderAboutus(width: 3)
        rulesbtn.addLeftBorderHistory(width: 3)
        generalbtn.addLeftBorderShare(width: 3)
        publickbtn.addLeftBorderHome(width: 3)
        contactusbtn.addLeftBorderAboutus(width: 3)
    }
}
```

but this is not called until i click back from child ... but when first click on the tab it will not be called!

why? and how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution ..

I just added the following:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
 }
```

In the navigation controller, and it was solved! :)

Comment: great keep going :)

Comment: @V_rohit Thanks alot!

Comment: @Lama is your issue resolved then accept the answer.

Comment: @PiyushRathi it is solved, but i only can accept my own answer after two days from today :)

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue many times, Make sure you are not calling any wrong super class method in child class i.e. For example, in your viewWillAppear you'r not calling the viewDidAppear method. or vice-versa.
This is compilers undefined behaviour. It mostly occurs in parent child view_controller's hierarchy.

For your solution, you can execute the code with small delay from viewWillAppear.

Comment: How to do the delay?

Comment: also am not sure of your point.. am calling the viewdidappear in the main tab controller .. and am not calling viewwillappear at all...

Comment: @Lama:-  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { }